# Why is it when I update a table in MS Access using Excel userform, data that need to updated is not visible?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I am creating a userform to update student attendance details. When updating a table in MS Access via Excel userform, the data is not updated. Instead it shows 0 or -1 on attendanceStatus column and nothing in the Excuse column[this is a picture of my ClassDate table after attempting to update for student IT01 and IT02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFrK.png).

My userform contains values for courseCode, subject, classDate, studentID, name, attendance status, and excuse. Therefore, I will be using the values of classDate, courseCode, and studentID to find the attendance of the student whom I want to update. This is my attempt for the Userform update button to update the attendanceStatus and Excuse column in the MS Access ClassDate table.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim db_path As String
Dim db_str As String

db_path = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\BIT\SEM4\SAD\StudentAttendanceMonitoring\attendance1.accdb;"
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

db_str = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & db_path
cnt.Open (db_str)

insert_str = "update Classdate set attendanceStatus = '" & cmbUpdateStatus.Value & "' and Excuse = '" & txtUpdateExcuse.Value & "' where classDate = '" & cmbUpdateDate.Value & "' and courseCode = '" & cmbUpdateCourseCode.Value & "' and studentID = '" & cmbUpdateStudentID.Value & "'"

Debug.Print insert_str

cnt.Execute (insert_str)

MsgBox "Updated sucessfully", vbInformation

Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not visible" - not visible where?

Comment: @June7 In my MS Access ClassDate table as shown in the picture attached. The column attendanceStatus and Excuse should be populated with data such as "Present", "Absent", "Absent with excuse" and "Reason for absent" respectively when updated using my Excel userform.

Comment: And what does the Debug.Print show is captured in the construct? Are all these fields text type?

Comment: @June7 Debug. Print shows = update Classdate set attendanceStatus = 'Absent with excuse' and Excuse = 'Fever' where classDate = '17/11/2022' and courseCode = 'ITWA' and studentID = 'IT01' . Yes all fields in my ClassDate table are of text type except for classDateID which is auto-number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be a comma to separate field update expressions, not `and`.

```
insert_str = "update Classdate set attendanceStatus = '" & cmbUpdateStatus.Value & _
                               "', Excuse = '" & txtUpdateExcuse.Value & _
             "' where classDate = '" & cmbUpdateDate.Value & _
                    "' and courseCode = '" & cmbUpdateCourseCode.Value & _
                    "' and studentID = '" & cmbUpdateStudentID.Value & "'"
```

Comment: It works perfectly now! This is a big part of my system and it's been bothering me for the whole day, you solved it in less than one hour. Thank you @June7. If you have any suggestions on how I can improve my code, do share.

Comment: Improve ? - don't use Excel as GUI. If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.